# How do I Put Bottom-shape of the Background Image HTML?

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to design the bottom of the background image of my web page ,
I have the Shape image how can i put that above the Background Image so that the shape will take place over the image,
If i am putting that shape image above the bg-color the shape is fitted but not working in in the background image

**Want to Use this shape**
[image]

**In this packground i want to put that shape in the bottom how can i do that?**
[image]

**Expected**

[image]

Comment: can you make those design in figma and capture it. so we all can understand what you want. it's abstaract.

Comment: I have edited and added the expected picture @DimasWahyuNotonagoro

Comment: Looks like you need a CSS mask effect. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask

Comment: here the example https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_mask-image

Answer (score 0):

here, you can have it

```css
.element {  
  border: 3rem solid transparent;
  padding: 5rem;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/khXzfxr/imageedit-2-5367723048.png);
          mask-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/khXzfxr/imageedit-2-5367723048.png);
  -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
          mask-size: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
          mask-repeat: no-repeat;
 
  -webkit-mask-clip: border-box;
  mask-clip: border-box;
  
  
  
  
  
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/moYqf.png');
  background-origin: border-box;  
  line-height: 1.6;  
  color: #646464;
  color: #fff;
}

body { 
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 2px dashed #ddd;
}


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courgette&display=swap');
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In here, i edited your image to remove the white color to transperent and fill the black color to white.